# Cookies without samesite attribute are not stored in chrome storage?

Tags: google-chrome, cookies, samesite

I am trying to understand how this new samesite rule https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5088147346030592 is affecting my website.

So I have a website under domain `a.com`. When customer visit this website I am calling under the hood partner website `b.com` which reply with http 200 ok and set tracking cookie on this response. This cookie is for domain `b.com` and without `samesite` attribute. We are using this mechanism so we can track customers that are visiting site a.com and then going to b.com to do some business action. This way `a.com` can get part of the commission from `b.com` for customers that previously visited `a.com`.

My question is does this new samesite changes are affecting this approach? In my understanding this cookies are drooped for `b.com` domain(even they are called from a.com) and they are after read on `b.com`. So the fact that they are without samesite attribute(default to samesite=Lax) should not affect this approach. However in network tab in google chrome i can see that chrome is putting warning to this cookie(just example cookie picture):

[image]

Also if I search for this cookie in browser storage it is not there? Does this mean that chrome is rejecting this cookie now?

Any help is appreciated. :)

Answer (score 0):

Where you want cookies set for cross-site usage, they must specify both `SameSite=None` and `Secure`. See https://web.dev/samesite-cookies-explained

Comment: Tnx @rowan_m.In my case I inject via iframe image from website `b.com` on my site `a.com`. Image from `b.com` is setting cookie on its response. But that cookie is not read by `a.com` or `b.com` while user is on`a.com` domain. Basically I am loading from `b.com` just 1x1 pixel image that sets cookie on response and I want that when user goes after my site to `b.com` site that this cookie is read on `b.com` domain(first party). Will in this case browser reject image cookie(e.g. not store it) as it is third party cookie, or cookie is stored but just not sent if it has wrong 'same site' settings?

Comment: additional not is that 'b.com' should read that cookie not on first landing call from 'a.com' but on some subsequent calls, so origin will be 'b.com'.